# UIButton frame doesn't layout as expected in viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, autolayout, cornerradius

[image: UIViewController Layout]

Here's my layout, I add a UIButton to UIView, and set its background.

I'm trying to set it to a circle, so the cornerRadius must be height/2 .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self initView];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
- (void)initView {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.userHeadImageButton.frame));
        //头像圆角
        CGFloat width = self.userHeadImageButton.frame.size.width;
        self.userHeadImageButton.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        self.userHeadImageButton.layer.cornerRadius = width/2;
    //    self.userHeadImageButton.layer.cornerRadius = 64;
}
```

The frame of the UIButton is supposed to {{136, 84}, {128, 128}}. and it should become a circle.

but the log is `[13821:81357] {{-23, -15}, {46, 30}}` and the effect is doing a cornerRadius, not a circle.

I don't know what's going on. Can anybody help me, thanks

Comment: where exactly have you written this code. My guess is it should be present in `viewDidAppear`. If it is before that it might not work as autolayout would not have set the width by then. Or maybe in `viewDidLayoutSubview`. Also try to align it with left and top constraints and check... Just a trial and error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that when `viewDidLoad` is called the auto layout constraints would not have been evaluated to determine the exact position and size of the views on the screen, so that's why your button would have some wacky position/size values.

If you implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews` in your view controller with the following, hopefully you'll see a circular image.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
  CGFloat width = self.userHeadImageButton.frame.size.width;
  self.userHeadImageButton.layer.cornerRadius = width / 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I got one more question here. I use my original method in another viewController, it works, it's UIImageView instead of a UIView, Does that matter?. How could they act different with the same method?

Comment: It doesn't matter. UimageView derives from UIView. So it should work. but you should be careful while using viewDidLayoutSubViews as it is always called whenever something changes in your view.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want to do it with StoryBoard than there is another way and also no need of manage view lifeCycle

Just add two User Defined RunTime Attributes

[image: Chech this]

layer.cornerRadius with type number and put half of your button's height!
layer.masksToBounds as boolean YES

please make sure do only if you button height is fixed